# How to use conditional rendering inside map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react page that is rendering a list of products that are being returned from a GraphQL API. Once the products are returned, I'm storing them in a state and then render them. How do I only render products that meet certain conditions?

Right now, I'm mapping over the products and rendering each one. This is working correctly. But if I try to use conditional statements, I get errors in my IDE. This is the code I currently have. This is currently working:

```
async function contactAPI() {
  return await axios({
    url: 'https://graphqlexample.com/api/products',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      query: `
      QUERY GOES HERE
        `
    }
  })
}

function App() {  
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const res = await contactAPI();
      setProducts(res.data.data.products);
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        <div>          
          {products.map(p =>           
          (             
          <div>            
            <ProductCard productName={p.productName} />
          </div>
          ))}
        </div>    
    </div>
  );
}
```

I need to check `p.productName` to see if it meet certain conditions, and if it does, render it. If not, don't render. I tried using different conditionals inside of `map`, but keep getting errors.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` will always return an array of the same length so you'll be returning some empty elements depending on the condition which isn't optimal.

Instead [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the data first, and *then* `map` over the returned array. That way you're only mapping over the data you need to display.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App({ data }) {

  const [ products, setProducts ] = useState(data);

  // In this example we take the list of products in
  // state and return a new array of only those products
  // that aren't soap. We then `map` over that array in our
  // component render
  function getFilteredProducts() {
    return products.filter(product => {
      const name = product.productName.toLowerCase();
      return !name.includes('soap');
    });
  }

  // Get an array of filtered products and then `map` over it
  // to produce the product cards
  return (
    <div>
      {getFilteredProducts().map(product => {
        return (
          <ProductCard
            key={product.id}
            id={product.id}
            name={product.productName}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

function ProductCard({ id, name}) {
  return <div>{id}: {name}</div>;
}

const data=[{id:1,productName:"Blue Soap"},{id:2,productName:"Beans"},{id:3,productName:"Green Soap"},{id:4,productName:"Sponge"},{id:5,productName:"Chicken"}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <App data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As an example you can just return the `JSX` if it will meet certain criterion as:

**Note:** For demo purpose I've used `includes` method. You can specify the condition

```
(<div><ProductCard productName={p.productName} /></div>)
```

and will only render if the first condition is `true`

```
  <div>
    {products.map((p) => (
      p.productName.includes("free") && (<div><ProductCard productName={p.productName} /></div>)
    ))}
  </div>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
export default function App() {
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  return (
    <div>
      {arr.map((n) => {
        return n % 2 === 0 && <div key={n}>{n}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    products.map(id => {
      return condition == true ?
        <div>            
          <ProductCard productName={p.productName} />
        </div>
    : <div></div>
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const products = [
  { productName: "product1" },
  { productName: "product2" },
  { productName: "product3" }
];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {products.map((p, index) => {
          if (p.productName === "product1") {
            return <div key={index}>{p.productName}</div>;
          }
          return <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```