# Handling errors in useEffect when fetching data from an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a react app that is fetching data from a GraphQL API. I'm doing this inside a `useEffect` hook. What is the best way to implement error handing? For now I just want to console log any returned errors.

I tried using `try.. catch`, but any errors returned from the API are not being console logged. What is the correct way of using try/catch in `useEffect`? Or what would be a better way of doing this?

```
async function contactAPI() {
  return await axios({
    url: 'https://graphqlexample.com/products/api',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      query: `
      QUERY GOES HERE
        `
    }
  })
}

function App() {  
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  try {
    useEffect(() => {
      async function getData() {
        const resp = await contactAPI();
        setProducts(resp.data.data.products);
      }
      getData();
    }, []);    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("there was an error:", err);
  }

  return (
    // JSX GOES HERE
  );
}
```

Comment: I love it when my code comes back to haunt me :)

Comment: I've seen this code before. Isn't it [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69784118/how-to-use-conditional-rendering-inside-map-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

You should cover with try-catch the exact line which may cause a problem, not a `useEffect` nor `getData`, so try this instead:

```
async function getData() {
  try {
    const resp = await contactAPI();
    setProducts(resp.data.data.products);
  } catch (err) {
    console.err("there was an error:", err);
  }
}
```